# When to use @ vs $ in R?

Tags: r, object, containers, data-analysis

My understanding is that `"@"` accesses the different containers of data within an overarching class object, while `"$"` is used to access a specific variable within that container.

e.g.

```
bmi <- atlas1006@sam_data$bmi_group
```

I believe I'm accessing the `bmi_group` variable in the `sam_data` container that's in the `atlass1006` object.

Is this use of `"@"` and `"$"` universally true, or are there other applications of `"@"` and `"$"` in R?

Thanks!

Comment: when the object is S4 class use `@` but when S3 use `$`

Comment: for more information on S3 and S4 classes see here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the `$` is used to extract details from `S3` object and also used on vectors, matrices, arrays and lists to extract or replace parts. in R and `@` is used to extract the contents of a slot in a object with a formal (`S4`) class structure.

You can type the below in R to know more information:

```
?'@'
```

```
Extract or Replace A Slot

Description

Extract or replace the contents of a slot in a object with a formal (S4) class structure.

Usage

object@name
object@name <- value
Arguments

object  
An object from a formally defined (S4) class.
name    
The character-string name of the slot, quoted or not. Must be the name of a slot in the definition of the class of object.
value   
A replacement value for the slot, which must be from a class compatible with the class defined for this slot in the definition of the class of object.
Details

These operators support the formal classes of package methods, and are enabled only when package methods is loaded (as per default).
......
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct (or at the very least, it's incomplete). `$` has nothing to do with S3 objects. `$` can act on vectors, matrices, arrays and lists, and is used to extract/replace parts of afore-mentioned objects. `$` is also used to access methods of `R6` objects, and fields of Refclass objects (similar to the slot operator `@` for S4 objects).

Comment: I agree with you `$` is more generic and can be used with vectors, matrices, arrays and lists to extract (this is mentioned in official docs of R) or replace parts, but the major difference is still that `@` only works on `S4` objects.

Comment: Yes, but OP's question was about when to use `$` vs. `@`. While you are quite correct about the use of `@` as the `S4` slot accessor, the usage of `$` is more complex (as I said, `$` can be used in the context of other OOP systems like `R6` and reference classes). So your answer is both incomplete and partially incorrect (about the link between `$` and `S3`).